# Connecting to Boost Signals2 signal with anonymous or lambda function

Tags: c++, events, boost, signals

I am trying to do the following in order to receive a string from a boost signal and post it to the display. The following syntax is incorrect.

```
signal<void (const char*)>                      UserMessageEvent;

// connect anonymous boost function to display message box on user message event 
UserMessageEvent.connect(boost::bind(AfxMessageBox, _1));
```

If this were C# I would do the following, leading me to believe I want to use a lambda function to convert between the calling type of the signal and the type of the AfxMessageBox arguments. However it is not clear to me how to do this.

```
UserMessageEvent += (c) => MessageBox.Show((some const char to LPCSTR conversion)c);
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:
The error given by msvc10 is error C2914: 'boost::bind' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous

Comment: Are you sure that your example doesn't work? I don't see why it wouldn't in regard to boost::signal...

Comment: I think it is something to do with the three parameters of AfxMessageBox, or that the const char * to LPCSTR conversion has to be explicit in some way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how boost::bind behave in regard to default parameters.

Anyway, here is the syntax with lambda :

```
UserMessageEvent.connect( [](const char* message)
{
   // maybe need here a conversion to LPCWSTR ?
   AfxMessageBox(message);
});
```

Comment: This works exactly as I had intended. It turns out there is no need to convert from the const char * type. The boost lambda function documentation isn't very clear about this stuff!

Comment: Does boost Signal2 support stated (capturing) lambdas, too?

Answer (score 3):

AfxMessageBox has several overloads and default parameters, which makes your construct above ambigious. Write a small function taking exactly one LPCSTR, which forwards to AfxMessageBox, and bind that to the signal<>.

EDIT:
As some people seem not to like what I provided above (why downvote without a comment?) here some clarifying code for what I wrote above:

```
int MyMessageBox(LPCSTR msg)
{
    return AfxMessageBox(msg);
}

UserMessageEvent.connect(boost::bind(MyMessageBox, _1));
```

Comment: In terms of the question asked, this is the correct answer (due to function overloads). `boost::bind` doesn't know which version of the overload to call.

Answer (score 0):

AfxMessageBox is __stdcall function, to support such functions you need to define BOOST_BIND_ENABLE_STDCALL before #include:

```
#define  BOOST_BIND_ENABLE_STDCALL
#include <boost\bind.hpp>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
  boost::bind<int, LPCTSTR>(
    &AfxMessageBox, L"", 0, 0);
  }
```